# Why does find not find my directory neither with -name nor with -regex

Tags: find, pattern-matching

I have a directory `~/Documents/machine_learning_coursera/`.

The command

```
find . -type d -name '^machine'
```

does not find anything

I also tried

```
find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '^machine'
```

so as to match the the beginning of the string and nothing.

I tried also with `-name`:

```
find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex -name '^machine'
```

and got the error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: `^machine'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`find`'s `-name` takes a shell/glob/`fnmatch()` wildcard pattern, not a regular expression.

GNU `find`'s `-regex` non-standard extension does take a regexp (old style emacs type by default), but that's applied on the full path (like the standard `-path` which also takes wildcards), not just the file name (and are anchored implicitly)

So to find files of type *directory* whose name starts with `machine`, you'd need:

```
find . -name 'machine*' -type d
```

Or:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/machine[^/]*' -type d
```

(for that particular regexp, you don't need `-regextype posix-extended` as the default regexp engine will work as well)

Note that for the first one to match, the *name* of the file also needs to be valid text in the locale, while for the second one, it's the full path that needs to be valid text.

Answer (score 11):

The argument for `-name` is much like a shell glob, so it's implicitly bound to the start and end of the filename it's matching, and you need `*` to indicate there may be more to come:

```
find . -type d -name 'machine*'
```

For your alternatives, `-regex` is documented (see `man find`) as "*a match on the whole path, not a search*", also implicitly bound to the start and end of the match, so you'd need

```
find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '(.*/)?machine[^/]*'
```

When you say that you "*tried also with `-name`*", you forgot that `-regex` requires a parameter, so it used `-name` as that parameter and then choked on the unexpected `'^machine'`

Comment: "The argument for -name is much like a shell glob": Is it in any way different to a shell glob? I had always thought it _was_ a shell glob, just one that is handled by `find` and not by the shell.

Comment: @terdon it doesn't handle braces, which are supported by some shells such as `bash`

Comment: not that I know of, just learning some bash. thanks!

Comment: `'(.*/)?machine.*'` would also match on files inside those directories as it matches on `./machine/some/dir` as well. The `(`, and `)?` are unnecessary as all file paths (except `.` itself) start with `./`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah yes, thank you. I've modified the `.*` appropriately. I've left the `(.*/)` because it will match even when someone else changes the starting directory to something other than `.` such that `machine` matches at the top level

Comment: well, braces `{}` aren't really part of glob patterns, but a different thing, regardless of the find man page confusing them... `{a,b}` expands to `a`, `b` even if those files don't exist, unlike what happens with a glob.

Comment: @ilkkachu if the man pages confuse them what hope have learners got?

Answer (score 6):

The `-name` test of `find`, does not take regular expressions, it takes file globs. The `^` has no special meaning in globs, so your command is looking for directories actually named `^machine`. You want this, which will find all directories whose name starts with `machine`:

```
find . -type d -name 'machine*'
```

Your other attempt failed because `-regex` is like `-name`. It isn't a flag to enable, you need to pass it a regular expression as input. Here you gave it nothing, so `find` complained. Also, note that the `-regex` test will try to match the entire path, not just the name. The right way to do what you want using the `-regex` test would be something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/machine.*'
```

Comment: globbing is filename generation, a feature of the shell that takes a wildcard pattern and uses it to generate a list of file paths that match them using a special algorithm. Note that `^` is a zsh extendedglob operator (negation there)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, in bash also, but not in the basic glob expansion used by `find` as far as I know. And while globbing is indeed a shell feature, it is also a `find` feature and `find` uses a very similar mechanism (identical?) to regular, simple file globbing. Or is that wrong?

Comment: `find` doesn't *generate* a list of files, it's `-name` just does pattern matching. It descends the directory tree regardless of whether you use `-name` or any other condition predicate. A shell expanding a `foo*/*bar` glob, based on that pattern will list the current directory, find the directory files that match `foo*` and then list those to find the files that match `*bar` for instance. shell globbing, the case construct and find's `-name`/`-path` all use shell wildcards (also often called glob patterns, as that comes fro the `glob` utility from Unix V1), but they are very different things.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas So, this *pattern matching* (any official term for it?) done by find command in `find . -type d -name 'machine*'` differs from its regex variant in 2 ways - a) usage of `-regex` option b) we are limited to use shell wildcards only when regex option not used.

Comment: @Number945 `-name 'machine*'` will match `machine`,  `machine1`, `machineasdkajhsd;jahsdd` and anything else starting with `machine`. If it were a regex, `machine*` only matches `machin`, `machinee`, `machinee`, `machineeeeeee` etc.

Comment: @Number945, there's no *`-regex` option*, there are `-name <wildcard-pattern>`, `-path <wildcard-pattern>`, `-regex <regexp>` *predicates*. On BSDs, there is a `-E` *option* that has the same effect as GNU's `-regex-type posix-extended` *option  predicate*.