# Understanding locate command regex

Tags: command-line, locate

To use `locate` command with regex , do we need to enclose the pattern in quotes along with passing `--regex` option ? If yes, then what do the following mean -

a) `locate --regex file*` ? Here regex will happen or shell globbing ?

b) `locate 'file*'` ? Will locate do regex search even though we did not passed `--regex` ?

c) `locate file*`  // I understand shell globbing will happen

d) `locate --regex 'file*'` // I understand regex search will happen in Database file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You type the command at the shell prompt. The shell processes what you typed, which includes globbing, substituting variables, substituting `$()` and so on. After processing what you typed, the shell executes the command.

Quotes are needed if a string contains characters that are special to the shell, such as spaces or asterisks, but you don't want the shell to process them. You will get away without quoting an asterisk if there are no matching files in the current directory, but it's good practice to quote it anyway.

It is important to understand that the `--regex` option has no effect on the shell's actions. First, the shell processes the command that you type. `locate` gets the result of that processing.

a) If there are files in the current directory that match `file*`, the shell will replace `file*` with the list of those files **before calling `locate`**. If there is no match, the shell won't touch `file*`, and locate looks for files that are named `file`, `filee`, `fileee` and so on.
In short, the shell attempts globbing, then `locate` performs a regular expression search if the shell's globbing results in correct syntax.

b) The quotes tell the shell to leave the asterisk alone. `locate` will look for files that start with `file`. No regex search.

c) The shell attempts globbing as in a). If there is no match, `locate` will look for files that start with `file`. No regex search.

d) The shell leaves the expression alone. `locate` will perform a regex search and look for files that are named `file`, `filee`, `fileee` and so on.

Comment: The behavior when there is no glob match depends on the shell (and shell options) - for example, bash by default passes the unexpanded glob pattern as you describe (with `failglob` and `nullglob` as options), whereas zsh would only pass the unmodified pattern to `locate` with option `nonomatch`. See for example [Why zsh tries to expand * and bash does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037419/4440445)

Comment: @berndbausch for b) is not that also a type of regex search ? Suppose I pass `locate '*file*'` , then locate will search for all file paths in Db having keyword `file` in it. So, is not it again a regex search ? If yes, then is not `--regex` redundant ?

Comment: @Number945 similar - but different. See for example [How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files)

Comment: @steeldriver The link explains wildcard meanings when used in globbing vs regex context. But my question is different. `locate '*file*'` , here locate is using to search through database and not shell expanding the wildcard. So, what is this process called ? Still we call it globbing or regex ?

Comment: @Number945 the exact terminology was discussed recently in comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631068/65304). I don't feel qualified to offer an opinion.

Comment: @Number945 `locate '*file*'` is *not* a regex search. It finds files that contain the string *file* (actually, the wildcards are redundant here).  `locate --regex '*file*'` is  regular expression search. It finds filenames that start with an asterisk, then *fil*, then any number of *e*'s.

Comment: @Number945 A clearer example, perhaps: `locate 's*p'` finds `sleep`, `smtp` among others. The asterisk stands for "any string". On the other hand, in `locate --regex 's*p'`, the asterisk means "a sequence of zero or more of the previous character", i.e. the empty string, a single *s*, or any number of *s*'s.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for pointing out that the shell's globbing behaviour is highly dependent on parameters and shell type. It's easy (for me) to overlook that.